# How to demo a static field is global to the application domain

Tags: c#

How to I write a code (maybe 2 applications) to access the same static field ? since it is global to app domain

Comment: I do not understand your question.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are looking for a sample to demonstrate that setting a static field will retain the value in all instances of your class, then the following demonstrates that the Person.Age field will be the value of whichever instance last set the value, but the Person.Name field will be the value of the current instance:

```
public class Person
{
    public static int Age;
    public string Name;

    public Person( int age, string name )
    {
        Age = age;
        Name = name;
    }

    public void Speak()
    {
        Console.WriteLine( "My name is {0} and I'm {1} years old.", Name, Age );
    }

}

public class StaticDemo
{

    static void Main( string[] args )
    {
        var fizz = new Person( 25, "Fizz" );
        fizz.Speak();
        var buzz = new Person( 30, "Buzz" );
        buzz.Speak();

        var people = new List<Person>
        {
          fizz,
          buzz,
          new Person( 35, "Foo" ),
          new Person( 40, "Bar" ),
        };

        foreach( Person person in people )
        {
            person.Speak();
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine( "--done--" );
        Console.ReadLine();

    }

}
```

**EDIT**: links and reference added.

[From MSDN static (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx.aspx):

> Use the static modifier to declare a
>   static member, which belongs to the
>   type itself rather than to a specific
>   object. The static modifier can be
>   used with classes, fields, methods,
>   properties, operators, events, and
>   constructors, but it cannot be used
>   with indexers, destructors, or types
>   other than classes.

[From the C# Language Specification: 10.4.5.1 Static field initialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645758(VS.71).aspx)

> The static field variable initializers
>   of a class correspond to a sequence of
>   assignments that are executed in the
>   textual order in which they appear in
>   the class declaration. If a static
>   constructor (Section 10.11) exists in
>   the class, execution of the static
>   field initializers occurs immediately
>   prior to executing that static
>   constructor. Otherwise, the static
>   field initializers are executed at an
>   implementation-dependent time prior to
>   the first use of a static field of
>   that class.

Answer (score 0):

Global to the app domain means that any code within your process can access the variable. You can demonstrate this by creating two distinct objects (class instances) that access the same static field.